# Different behavior in run and debugger option in Pycharrn. Is my code the issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, pycharm

I'm new to Python, and for my second project, I decided to create an easy number guessing game.  The issue that I'm running into is that when I run my code, it automatically jumps to the last elif statement and outputs " The number is higher. Please try again", even if I limit random.randint(1,1) and enter 1 as user input.  However, when I run my code through the debugger, everything seems to be working perfectly fine. Is there any way to fix this issue? I have already tried to restart Pycharm and update it but to no avail. Is my code the issue, or is it Pycharm?

```
import random

Question1 = input(" Please choose a number 1 to 1")
print("You chose"+ Question1)

Num = random.randint(1,1)
if Question1 == str(Num):
  print("Correct! The correct number was" + " " + str((Num)))
elif Question1 > str(Num):
      print("The number is lower. Please try again:")
elif Question1 < str(Num):
  print(" The number is higher. Please try again")
```

Output using "Run"

```
 Please choose a number 1 to 1 1
You chose 1
 The number is higher. Please try again
```

Output using "Debugger"

```
 Please choose a number 1 to 1You chose1
Correct! The correct number was 1
```

Thank you for the help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not at all a pycharm issue!
You need to convert `Question1` to `int` not `Num` to `str`

This what your code should look like :

```py
import random

Question1 = input(" Please choose a number 1 to 1")
print("You chose"+ Question1)

Num = random.randint(1,1)
if int(Question1) == Num:
  print("Correct! The correct number was" + " " + str((Num)))
elif int(Question1) > Num:
      print("The number is lower. Please try again:")
elif int(Question1) < Num:
  print(" The number is higher. Please try again")
```

Comparison operators (`+` . `-` . `*` , `/` etc.) are used only on the `int` values not the `str` values